# Creating a File Drop Zone using Angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I'm new to angular, and new to HTML for that matter, and I'm trying to set up a file drag and drop box. But it seems like all the tutorials I see online, just simply do not work for me. So I'll take this tutorial as an example on here:

https://codingdiksha.com/angular-drag-and-drop-multiple-files-upload-to-firebase-storage-using-angularfire2/

Specifically it has the following:

```
<div class="dropzone" 
     dropzone
     (hovered)="toggleHover($event)"
     (dropped)="onDrop($event)"
     [class.hovering]="isHovering">
```

I have come to the conclusion that hovered and dropped are simply not events. Obviously the intent is when I hover, the event (hovered) is supposed to call my toggleHover method in the .TS file. But this doesn't happen. If I use mouseenter instead of hovered, the method is called.

Does the stackOverflow community agree that hovered is not really an event? If it is an event, why does mouseenter work and not hovered?

Further more, every tutorial I have tried to follow, whenever I place a file over the drop zone, my chrome simply downloads the file to my hard drive. It does that anywhere on the screen, including my drop zone. In the tutorial I'm copying, the file is uploaded instead. Most tutorials I have seen for angular, use something along the lines of this:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onDrop($event)">
```

Is my code simply not calling the onDrop method, and that's why my browser is simply downloading my file and acting like a drop file zone doesn't even exist?

I know this is a little vague, but I'm hoping someone on here can give me some sort of direction. Perhaps a useful tutorial I haven't come across yet. Thanks for any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: the `input` with type="file" is needed to show the choose file dialog from your os. Many examples set this input to hidden and simulate a click on it.

Then (in your example you wanna use a directive) the directive needs all the functions as drag and drop need.

```
export class FileDragNDropDirective {
  //@Input() private allowed_extensions : Array<string> = ['png', 'jpg', 'bmp'];
  @Output() private filesChangeEmiter : EventEmitter<File[]> = new EventEmitter();
  //@Output() private filesInvalidEmiter : EventEmitter<File[]> = new EventEmitter();
  @HostBinding('style.background') private background = '#eee';
  @HostBinding('style.border') private borderStyle = '2px dashed';
  @HostBinding('style.border-color') private borderColor = '#696D7D';
  @HostBinding('style.border-radius') private borderRadius = '5px';

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) public onDragOver(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.background = 'lightgray';
    this.borderColor = 'cadetblue';
    this.borderStyle = '3px solid';
  }

  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.background = '#eee';
    this.borderColor = '#696D7D';
    this.borderStyle = '2px dashed';
  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public onDrop(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.background = '#eee';
    this.borderColor = '#696D7D';
    this.borderStyle = '2px dashed';
    debugger;
    let files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    let valid_files : Array<File> = files;
    this.filesChangeEmiter.emit(valid_files);
  }
}
```

*And here is a sample HTML snippet:*

```
<div class="dropzone" fileDragDrop (filesChangeEmiter)="onFileChange($event)">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <div class="centered">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="onFileChange($event.target.files)" multiple>
            <label for="file"><span class="textLink">Select your file</span> or Drop it here!</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All other you can see in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/file-upload-drag-n-drop-hye6lv?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example.